# unable to do sectioning while merging multiple documents(.docx)

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

while merging multiple word documents(.docx) , if few of the documents have unique  Headers and Footer, then, only one header applies to the merged  document, but it should not. 
Expected output: Respective Headers of individual doc should apply to the respective section in the merged doc.
 Unable to do sectioning logic,  please suggest solution.
Used technologies java, Apache POI (XWPF).

Comment: Without any code, we can't really see what you're doing wrong...

Comment: In addition, XWPF is not particularly complete when it comes to sections. The only way to deal with them is down at the schema level.